# writting in a txt file will omit some value

Tags: python, list, text

In my little program, I use the

```
file = open("txtfile.txt", "w")
file.write(my_string)
file.close
```

the string is actually a list, just converted into a str using str(my_list), the problem comes when I open the file. it looks fine at first but if you go to the end of it, you will see that there is some values that are missing, including the bracket closing the list. here is the testable code:

```
import ast

### dont worry about the function
def p5map(n, start1, stop1, start2, stop2):
    return ((float(n)-start1)/(stop1-start1))*(stop2-start2)+start2 

### what is inside the txt file will be at the end, just copy and paste it 
###                                          in a txt file named "best_DNA"

with open("best_DNA.txt", "r") as f:
    pop = ast.literal_eval(f.readline().rstrip())


### this is just to convert what is in the txt file into what I want

maxLenPerState = 16*3+1
maxState = 36

newInput = [[] for _ in xrange(len(pop))]
temp = [0 for _ in xrange(maxState*maxLenPerState)]

for cube in xrange(len(pop)):
    newInput[cube] = temp
    for state in xrange(len(pop[cube])):
        newInput[cube][state*maxLenPerState] = p5map(state, 0, maxState-1, 0, 1)

###  if you actually print the newInput, you will see that at the end of it, 
###                                             there is the closing bracket
print newInput


### here is where I write into the file, **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE NO IMPORTANT TXT
###                                              FILE NAMED "test0" !!!!!!!!**

mystr = str(newInput)
#print mystr    #you can even print the string version of "newInput" and the closing bracker are here
file = open("test0.txt", "w")
file.write(mystr)
file.close
```

now if you open the test0.txt you will see that there is the closing bracket missing and some value too, why is that?

what should go into your "best_DNA" txt file:

```
[[[(0, 0, -1, -1), (1, 0, 0.0625), (-1, 0, 3.0625), (1, 1, 9.0625), (1, 0, -4.9375), (-1, 1, -5.9375), (-1, -1, -4.9375), (-1, -1, 1.0625), (0, 0, -0.9375), (-1, -1, -0.9375), (1, 1, -1.9375), (0, -1, 8.0625), (0, -1, 5.0625), (0, -1, 7.0625), (1, 1, -2.9375), (-1, 0, 4.0625), (1, -1, 5.0625)], [(0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1.3125), (-1, 1, 0.3125), (0, 1, 6.3125), (-1, -1, -0.6875), (1, 0, 6.3125), (0, -1, -5.6875), (1, -1, -0.6875), (1, -1, 3.3125), (0, 0, 1.3125), (0, -1, -6.6875), (1, 0, 2.3125), (-1, 0, 3.3125), (0, -1, -6.6875), (1, 0, 8.3125), (1, 1, -0.6875), (0, 1, 8.3125)], [(0, 0, -1, 1), (-1, 1, 0.6875), (1, 1, -4.3125), (0, 0, -0.3125), (-1, 0, 9.6875), (0, 0, 0.6875), (1, 0, 0.6875), (-1, 1, 8.6875), (-1, -1, -2.3125), (0, 0, 1.6875), (-1, 0, -3.3125), (-1, 1, 1.6875), (1, -1, 5.6875), (1, -1, 7.6875), (0, 0, -5.3125), (-1, -1, 2.6875), (-1, -1, -4.3125)], [(0, 0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 3.125), (0, 1, 0.125), (1, -1, -1.875), (-1, -1, -7.875), (0, -1, 6.125), (1, 0, 1.125), (-1, 0, -3.875), (1, 0, 5.125), (1, -1, 1.125), (1, 1, 5.125), (0, 0, -1.875), (1, 1, 4.125), (0, -1, 4.125), (1, 0, -4.875), (0, 1, 7.125), (-1, 1, 3.125)], [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0.3125), (1, -1, 6.3125), (-1, -1, -6.6875), (1, 0, 7.3125), (-1, -1, -6.6875), (0, -1, -3.6875), (-1, 0, 6.3125), (0, 1, 1.3125), (1, 0, 7.3125), (1, 1, -6.6875), (1, -1, -4.6875), (0, 0, 5.3125), (0, 1, -4.6875), (1, 0, 6.3125), (-1, 1, 6.3125), (1, -1, 6.3125)], [(0, 0, 0, 1), (0, -1, 9.6875), (-1, -1, 6.6875), (0, 0, -0.3125), (-1, 1, -5.3125), (-1, 0, -4.3125), (0, -1, 7.6875), (0, 0, 0.6875), (-1, 0, -3.3125), (1, 1, 7.6875), (1, 0, 4.6875), (-1, -1, -5.3125), (-1, -1, 0.6875), (1, -1, 2.6875), (-1, -1, -3.3125), (1, -1, -0.3125), (0, 1, 1.6875)], [(0, 0, 1, -1), (-1, 0, 4.1875), (-1, 1, 0.1875), (-1, 0, -1.8125), (-1, 0, 2.1875), (1, -1, 4.1875), (0, 0, -5.8125), (1, 1, 7.1875), (0, 0, 7.1875), (0, 0, -6.8125), (1, 0, -2.8125), (1, 0, 1.1875), (-1, 1, 7.1875), (1, 1, 7.1875), (0, 1, 2.1875), (1, 1, 0.1875), (0, 0, -5.8125)], [(0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, -6.6875), (0, 0, -3.6875), (-1, 0, -2.6875), (0, -1, 8.3125), (-1, 0, 2.3125), (1, -1, 3.3125), (0, 0, 1.3125), (0, 0, 4.3125), (1, -1, 8.3125), (-1, 0, 0.3125), (-1, -1, -5.6875), (1, 0, 6.3125), (1, -1, 5.3125), (1, 1, 8.3125), (0, 1, -6.6875), (0, -1, -2.6875)], [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1.0), (-1, 1, 7.0), (0, -1, -1.0), (1, -1, 3.0), (1, 1, 1.0), (1, 0, -1.0), (1, 0, 2.0), (1, 1, -3.0), (-1, 1, 1.0), (-1, 1, -2.0), (0, -1, -4.0), (1, -1, -2.0), (1, -1, -1.0), (0, 1, 1.0), (1, 1, 7.0), (-1, -1, 11.0)], [(0, 1, -1, -1), (0, 0, -2.375), (1, 1, 5.625), (-1, 1, 1.625), (-1, 1, -4.375), (-1, -1, -1.375), (1, 0, 5.625), (0, 1, -3.375), (0, -1, 8.625), (0, 0, -2.375), (-1, -1, 7.625), (1, 1, 8.625), (0, 1, -4.375), (-1, 1, -1.375), (0, 1, 4.625), (0, 0, -1.375), (-1, 1, -1.375)], [(0, 1, -1, 0), (-1, 0, 4.375), (-1, 1, -3.625), (1, 0, -3.625), (1, 1, 7.375), (1, -1, 0.375), (0, 0, 1.375), (-1, 1, 5.375), (1, 1, -0.625), (0, -1, -4.625), (0, 0, 0.375), (0, -1, -0.625), (-1, 1, 7.375), (-1, -1, 0.375), (-1, 0, 1.375), (-1, 0, 5.375), (0, 0, -0.625)], [(0, 1, -1, 1), (0, 1, 7.3125), (0, 0, 2.3125), (0, 0, 6.3125), (0, 1, -3.6875), (1, 0, 3.3125), (0, -1, -3.6875), (1, 1, -0.6875), (1, -1, 0.3125), (1, 1, 7.3125), (0, 1, -1.6875), (0, 0, 4.3125), (-1, 0, 3.3125), (-1, 1, -1.6875), (1, 0, -5.6875), (1, -1, -3.6875), (-1, -1, 6.3125)], [(0, 1, 0, -1), (-1, 0, -3.0625), (-1, 1, 3.9375), (-1, 1, 1.9375), (-1, -1, 2.9375), (0, 0, 5.9375), (0, -1, -2.0625), (-1, -1, -1.0625), (-1, 0, -7.0625), (1, 0, 2.9375), (-1, 1, -2.0625), (-1, 0, 0.9375), (1, -1, 2.9375), (1, 0, 6.9375), (1, -1, -2.0625), (1, 1, 1.9375), (1, -1, 6.9375)], [(0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, -2.75), (-1, 0, 8.25), (1, 1, 8.25), (-1, -1, 0.25), (1, -1, -3.75), (-1, -1, 7.25), (-1, 1, 2.25), (0, 0, 8.25), (0, 1, -5.75), (1, 0, -3.75), (-1, -1, 8.25), (-1, 1, -5.75), (-1, 0, 2.25), (1, -1, -1.75), (0, 0, 3.25), (-1, 0, -4.75)], [(0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1.0), (-1, -1, 1.0), (-1, -1, 5.0), (-1, -1, -6.0), (-1, 1, 4.0), (-1, 1, 2.0), (0, -1, 5.0), (-1, 1, 1.0), (0, 1, 0.0), (1, 1, -6.0), (0, 1, -1.0), (1, 1, -1.0), (-1, 1, 8.0), (0, -1, 4.0), (1, 0, 0.0), (-1, 0, 5.0)], [(0, 1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, -3.0625), (1, 0, -3.0625), (-1, 1, -0.0625), (-1, 1, 1.9375), (1, 0, 8.9375), (1, -1, 6.9375), (0, 1, 5.9375), (1, 1, 0.9375), (-1, -1, 7.9375), (-1, 1, -3.0625), (-1, -1, -1.0625), (-1, -1, -1.0625), (-1, -1, -2.0625), (1, -1, 6.9375), (-1, 0, -3.0625), (1, 1, -3.0625)], [(0, 1, 1, 0), (-1, -1, 6.25), (-1, -1, 7.25), (0, -1, 4.25), (1, 1, 7.25), (1, 0, -1.75), (-1, 0, -4.75), (1, 0, -4.75), (1, 1, 2.25), (1, 1, -4.75), (1, -1, 5.25), (1, 1, -5.75), (1, -1, 8.25), (1, 0, 6.25), (1, -1, -4.75), (-1, 0, -1.75), (0, 1, 1.25)], [(0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, -3.3125), (-1, -1, 0.6875), (1, 0, 2.6875), (1, 0, -2.3125), (1, -1, -4.3125), (-1, -1, -5.3125), (1, -1, 7.6875), (1, -1, 6.6875), (1, -1, 3.6875), (-1, -1, 6.6875), (1, 1, -2.3125), (-1, 1, 4.6875), (-1, 0, 2.6875), (1, 1, -6.3125), (1, -1, 5.6875), (-1, 1, 2.6875)], [(1, 0, -1, -1), (1, -1, -1.0), (1, -1, 8.0), (0, 0, 1.0), (0, 1, 1.0), (0, 0, -2.0), (0, 1, -3.0), (-1, -1, 3.0), (1, 0, -6.0), (1, -1, -2.0), (1, 0, 4.0), (-1, 1, 7.0), (-1, 1, 8.0), (0, -1, -6.0), (-1, -1, 4.0), (0, -1, 6.0), (1, 1, -2.0)], [(1, 0, -1, 0), (-1, 0, 6.4375), (0, 0, 8.4375), (-1, 1, -2.5625), (-1, 0, 1.4375), (1, 1, -2.5625), (-1, 0, 5.4375), (1, 0, 7.4375), (1, 0, -6.5625), (0, 0, 3.4375), (0, 0, -4.5625), (1, 0, -5.5625), (1, 0, 3.4375), (0, -1, 0.4375), (-1, 0, -6.5625), (-1, -1, 7.4375), (1, 0, 4.4375)], [(1, 0, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -7.1875), (1, -1, 5.8125), (1, -1, 4.8125), (0, 0, -0.1875), (1, 1, 6.8125), (0, 1, 3.8125), (-1, -1, -4.1875), (0, 1, 3.8125), (1, 0, -8.1875), (0, -1, 1.8125), (1, -1, -0.1875), (1, -1, -2.1875), (-1, 0, 1.8125), (-1, 1, 6.8125), (1, -1, 1.8125), (-1, -1, 4.8125)], [(1, 0, 0, -1), (-1, -1, 5.8125), (-1, -1, -3.1875), (0, 0, 3.8125), (0, 0, -2.1875), (1, -1, 6.8125), (-1, 1, 0.8125), (1, -1, 4.8125), (-1, -1, 3.8125), (-1, 1, -4.1875), (0, 0, -1.1875), (0, -1, -0.1875), (-1, -1, 8.8125), (-1, 1, -4.1875), (-1, 0, 2.8125), (1, 0, -5.1875), (0, 0, 2.8125)], [(1, 0, 0, 0), (-1, 1, -0.8125), (1, 1, 3.1875), (1, 0, -5.8125), (0, 0, -2.8125), (0, 0, 1.1875), (1, 0, 7.1875), (1, -1, 2.1875), (1, -1, 5.1875), (0, -1, 6.1875), (1, 0, 3.1875), (0, 1, -0.8125), (0, -1, -4.8125), (-1, 0, 5.1875), (0, -1, 2.1875), (1, 0, 3.1875), (1, 0, -3.8125)], [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2.125), (0, 1, 6.125), (0, -1, 3.125), (-1, -1, 4.125), (0, -1, -5.875), (1, 1, 1.125), (0, 1, 5.125), (1, 0, -2.875), (0, -1, -3.875), (-1, 1, -1.875), (1, 0, 9.125), (-1, 1, -1.875), (-1, 1, -2.875), (-1, 0, 3.125), (1, 0, -3.875), (1, -1, 9.125)], [(1, 0, 1, -1), (-1, -1, -2.125), (1, 1, 5.875), (-1, 1, -5.125), (0, 1, 3.875), (0, 0, 3.875), (1, -1, 6.875), (-1, 1, 3.875), (1, -1, 4.875), (0, -1, 4.875), (0, 0, 1.875), (-1, -1, -3.125), (1, -1, 4.875), (1, 0, -7.125), (1, -1, 6.875), (0, 1, -7.125), (-1, 0, -3.125)], [(1, 0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 1.0625), (1, -1, -3.9375), (0, 0, 3.0625), (-1, 1, 2.0625), (-1, -1, 7.0625), (0, -1, 1.0625), (1, 1, -0.9375), (1, 1, -4.9375), (1, 0, 6.0625), (-1, 1, 9.0625), (1, 0, -4.9375), (1, 1, -1.9375), (1, 1, -0.9375), (-1, 1, 8.0625), (0, -1, -4.9375), (0, 0, 5.0625)], [(1, 0, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -5.5625), (1, 1, -6.5625), (-1, 1, -5.5625), (1, 0, 6.4375), (0, 0, -1.5625), (1, 0, 7.4375), (1, 1, 8.4375), (-1, 0, 2.4375), (0, 1, 1.4375), (-1, 0, 8.4375), (0, 1, 0.4375), (-1, -1, -2.5625), (-1, -1, -4.5625), (-1, 1, 8.4375), (-1, 1, 5.4375), (-1, 0, -2.5625)], [(1, 1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 2.9375), (-1, -1, 1.9375), (1, -1, 5.9375), (-1, 1, -0.0625), (-1, 1, -3.0625), (-1, -1, 6.9375), (1, 0, -3.0625), (0, -1, 9.9375), (0, 1, 2.9375), (0, 0, -5.0625), (-1, -1, -4.0625), (0, -1, 7.9375), (1, -1, -5.0625), (1, -1, 0.9375), (0, 0, 3.9375), (1, 0, -3.0625)], [(1, 1, -1, 0), (1, 0, -6.1875), (0, 0, 4.8125), (0, 1, -1.1875), (0, -1, 4.8125), (1, 1, 5.8125), (1, -1, 6.8125), (1, 1, 1.8125), (1, 0, 2.8125), (-1, 0, -1.1875), (-1, -1, -4.1875), (-1, 0, 6.8125), (0, 1, 5.8125), (1, 1, -8.1875), (-1, -1, -4.1875), (0, 0, 6.8125), (-1, 0, -1.1875)], [(1, 1, -1, 1), (-1, 0, 2.375), (0, 0, -4.625), (-1, 1, -5.625), (-1, 0, 0.375), (-1, 1, 8.375), (-1, 1, 6.375), (0, -1, 4.375), (0, 1, -0.625), (1, -1, 7.375), (0, -1, 7.375), (1, 1, 1.375), (-1, -1, -1.625), (1, 0, -4.625), (-1, 0, 5.375), (-1, 1, -0.625), (-1, 1, -5.625)], [(1, 1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, -4.75), (-1, 0, 2.25), (0, 0, 5.25), (1, 0, -4.75), (-1, -1, 1.25), (-1, 0, 2.25), (0, 1, -0.75), (0, 0, -4.75), (1, -1, 6.25), (-1, 1, -3.75), (-1, 0, 8.25), (0, -1, -1.75), (-1, 1, 6.25), (-1, 1, 6.25), (0, 0, 3.25), (0, 0, -0.75)], [(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 5.5), (-1, 0, -5.5), (0, -1, 7.5), (0, -1, -4.5), (-1, -1, 4.5), (1, 0, -4.5), (0, -1, 7.5), (-1, 0, -3.5), (0, 0, -2.5), (0, 1, 0.5), (0, -1, -0.5), (-1, 1, -0.5), (0, 1, -2.5), (0, 1, 7.5), (0, 0, 5.5), (0, 0, 5.5)], [(1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1.0625), (0, -1, -1.9375), (0, 1, 8.0625), (1, -1, 5.0625), (-1, 1, -4.9375), (-1, -1, 9.0625), (0, 1, -3.9375), (-1, -1, -4.9375), (0, 1, -4.9375), (-1, -1, 0.0625), (1, -1, 5.0625), (0, -1, -4.9375), (1, 0, 2.0625), (-1, -1, 10.0625), (0, 1, 9.0625), (1, 0, -3.9375)], [(1, 1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 0.375), (1, 0, 1.375), (0, -1, 10.375), (0, 0, 4.375), (-1, -1, -2.625), (1, 0, 8.375), (0, -1, -2.625), (-1, 0, -4.625), (-1, 1, 7.375), (-1, 1, 6.375), (0, 0, -4.625), (0, 0, 6.375), (-1, 0, -4.625), (0, 1, -0.625), (-1, 0, -4.625), (0, 1, -0.625)], [(1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0.125), (0, 0, 1.125), (1, 0, 1.125), (-1, 1, -5.875), (1, 0, 1.125), (1, 0, 8.125), (-1, -1, -3.875), (0, 1, 1.125), (-1, 1, 5.125), (-1, 1, -2.875), (1, 1, 4.125), (0, 1, -1.875), (1, -1, -0.875), (0, 1, 7.125), (1, 0, 0.125), (-1, 0, 6.125)], [(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, -1, -5.375), (-1, 0, -2.375), (1, 1, -4.375), (-1, 0, -2.375), (1, 0, 5.625), (0, -1, -1.375), (1, -1, -0.375), (0, 0, 3.625), (0, 0, 2.625), (0, 0, 1.625), (-1, 1, 7.625), (0, 1, 6.625), (1, 0, 7.625), (0, 1, -6.375), (-1, 1, 4.625), (1, 0, 2.625)]], [[(0, 0, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 5.9375), (0, -1, 2.9375), (0, -1, -4.0625), (-1, -1, 0.9375), (0, -1, -0.0625), (0, 0, 2.9375), (-1, -1, -1.0625), (1, 0, -3.0625), (1, 0, 0.9375), (1, 0, -2.0625), (-1, 0, 3.9375), (0, 1, 9.9375), (0, 0, -2.0625), (1, 0, 2.9375), (-1, 0, -2.0625), (0, 1, 3.9375)], [(0, 0, -1, 0), (1, 1, 9.6875), (-1, 0, 9.6875), (-1, 0, -3.3125), (-1, -1, 2.6875), (0, -1, -4.3125), (-1, 1, 6.6875), (0, 1, -4.3125), (-1, -1, -4.3125), (1, 1, 1.6875), (-1, 1, -3.3125), (1, 0, 0.6875), (1, 0, -3.3125), (0, 1, 10.6875), (-1, 1, -3.3125), (1, 0, 8.6875), (-1, -1, -4.3125)], [(0, 0, -1, 1), (-1, 0, 7.25), (1, -1, -5.75), (0, -1, 8.25), (-1, 0, 1.25), (0, -1, 4.25), (-1, 1, 3.25), (-1, 1, 7.25), (1, -1, -4.75), (0, 0, -4.75), (-1, -1, -3.75), (0, -1, 0.25), (1, 1, 5.25), (0, 0, 8.25), (0, 0, -4.75), (1, 0, 4.25), (0, -1, -5.75)], [(0, 0, 0, -1), (-1, 1, 6.4375), (-1, 1, -6.5625), (1, -1, -8.5625), (1, 0, 5.4375), (-1, -1, 6.4375), (-1, 1, 2.4375), (1, -1, 0.4375), (0, 0, 3.4375), (0, 1, -2.5625), (1, 1, 0.4375), (1, 1, -4.5625), (-1, 0, 5.4375), (0, 0, 6.4375), (-1, -1, 0.4375), (-1, 0, 3.4375), (1, 1, 1.4375)], [(0, 0, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 8.375), (-1, 1, -3.625), (0, 1, -4.625), (-1, 1, -4.625), (0, -1, -1.625), (-1, 0, 8.375), (-1, 1, 5.375), (-1, 1, -3.625), (1, 0, -2.625), (0, -1, 2.375), (1, -1, 6.375), (1, 0, 4.375), (-1, 1, -1.625), (-1, 1, 6.375), (0, 0, -3.625), (0, -1, 4.375)], [(0, 0, 0, 1), (0, -1, 6.0625), (1, -1, -3.9375), (1, -1, 5.0625), (0, -1, 8.0625), (1, -1, 0.0625), (0, 0, -0.9375), (-1, -1, 0.0625), (0, 0, -3.9375), (1, 0, 1.0625), (1, 0, 2.0625), (-1, 0, 1.0625), (-1, -1, -3.9375), (-1, 0, 9.0625), (0, 0, 3.0625), (1, 1, -1.9375), (-1, -1, -0.9375)], [(0, 0, 1, -1), (1, 1, 0.375), (0, 1, 1.375), (-1, 1, 1.375), (-1, 1, -2.625), (0, 0, -1.625), (1, -1, 8.375), (-1, 1, -3.625), (0, 1, 1.375), (-1, 0, 1.375), (-1, 1, 4.375), (1, -1, -1.625), (1, -1, 6.375), (1, 1, -0.625), (0, -1, 8.375), (0, 0, 1.375), (-1, 0, -4.625)], [(0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, -1.0625), (-1, 0, -1.0625), (0, -1, 0.9375), (-1, 1, -8.0625), (1, 1, 2.9375), (1, -1, 0.9375), (0, 1, -1.0625), (-1, -1, -0.0625), (1, 0, 1.9375), (-1, 0, 0.9375), (1, -1, 4.9375), (-1, 1, 3.9375), (0, 0, 4.9375), (-1, 1, 5.9375), (1, -1, -1.0625), (-1, 1, 4.9375)], [(0, 0, 1, 1), (-1, 1, -1.6875), (1, -1, 5.3125), (1, -1, -1.6875), (1, 1, 1.3125), (-1, -1, -2.6875), (0, 0, 11.3125), (0, 1, -2.6875), (-1, 1, -3.6875), (-1, 1, -0.6875), (0, -1, -2.6875), (-1, 0, 0.3125), (1, 0, 3.3125), (-1, -1, 4.3125), (1, 1, -0.6875), (0, 1, 5.3125), (-1, -1, 5.3125)], [(0, 1, -1, -1), (0, 0, -5.1875), (0, 1, 5.8125), (1, 1, 2.8125), (0, 1, -1.1875), (0, 0, 0.8125), (0, 0, -5.1875), (-1, 1, 3.8125), (-1, 1, 1.8125), (1, 1, 4.8125), (-1, 1, -1.1875), (-1, 1, -0.1875), (1, -1, -4.1875), (0, 0, 5.8125), (0, 1, 6.8125), (0, 1, 6.8125), (-1, 0, -2.1875)], [(0, 1, -1, 0), (0, 1, 0.25), (-1, 0, 3.25), (-1, 0, -4.75), (-1, 0, 1.25), (-1, 0, 6.25), (1, 0, 5.25), (-1, 0, -0.75), (0, 1, -5.75), (-1, 0, 4.25), (0, 0, -2.75), (0, -1, 7.25), (1, -1, -2.75), (1, 0, -1.75), (-1, 0, 7.25), (0, -1, -2.75), (0, 0, 6.25)], [(0, 1, -1, 1), (1, 0, 4.625), (1, -1, 3.625), (1, 1, 5.625), (1, 0, 8.625), (0, 1, 1.625), (-1, 0, -1.375), (-1, -1, -0.375), (1, -1, -6.375), (-1, 1, -6.375), (-1, -1, 2.625), (1, -1, 4.625), (-1, 0, -3.375), (1, 1, -0.375), (1, 0, -6.375), (-1, 0, 7.625), (0, 0, 5.625)], [(0, 1, 0, -1), (0, 1, 8.375), (-1, 1, 7.375), (1, 1, -3.625), (0, 1, 5.375), (1, -1, 7.375), (1, 0, -5.625), (-1, 0, -3.625), (0, 0, -1.625), (0, -1, -2.625), (1, 0, -1.625), (0, -1, 6.375), (0, -1, 2.375), (1, 1, -0.625), (-1, -1, -0.625), (1, -1, 3.375), (0, -1, -0.625)], [(0, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 7.5625), (0, 1, -3.4375), (0, 1, 7.5625), (1, 1, 6.5625), (0, -1, 4.5625), (-1, 0, -1.4375), (0, 1, -5.4375), (0, 1, -2.4375), (1, 0, 3.5625), (-1, 0, 5.5625), (1, -1, 3.5625), (-1, 1, -2.4375), (1, 1, 8.5625), (-1, -1, -5.4375), (-1, 0, -3.4375), (1, 1, -3.4375)], [(0, 1, 0, 1), (-1, -1, 1.75), (1, 0, -2.25), (0, 1, -4.25), (-1, -1, -0.25), (-1, -1, -0.25), (1, 0, -2.25), (1, 0, 5.75), (0, 0, 6.75), (0, 0, 1.75), (-1, -1, 0.75), (0, 0, 9.75), (-1, 0, 0.75), (-1, 1, -5.25), (0, 1, -2.25), (-1, -1, 8.75), (0, 0, 0.75)], [(0, 1, 1, -1), (0, -1, 0.0), (1, 1, -5.0), (0, -1, 1.0), (1, -1, 1.0), (0, -1, 1.0), (-1, 1, 8.0), (0, -1, 7.0), (-1, 1, -1.0), (-1, 1, -4.0), (-1, -1, 9.0), (1, -1, 0.0), (1, 1, -3.0), (-1, 0, -2.0), (1, 1, 8.0), (-1, -1, -6.0), (-1, -1, 6.0)], [(0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 2.4375), (1, 1, 4.4375), (1, 1, -6.5625), (-1, 0, 1.4375), (-1, 0, 3.4375), (1, 1, -3.5625), (1, 0, 0.4375), (0, 0, 5.4375), (-1, -1, -0.5625), (-1, 0, 2.4375), (0, 1, 4.4375), (-1, 1, -0.5625), (1, -1, -7.5625), (0, -1, 1.4375), (1, 1, 6.4375), (-1, 1, 6.4375)], [(0, 1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 0.375), (1, 0, -0.625), (0, -1, -7.625), (-1, -1, -5.625), (0, 1, 7.375), (-1, 1, -3.625), (-1, 0, 3.375), (0, -1, 7.375), (0, -1, 2.375), (0, -1, 3.375), (0, 1, 0.375), (-1, 1, 4.375), (-1, 1, 2.375), (1, 1, 7.375), (0, 1, -7.625), (0, 0, 6.375)], [(1, 0, -1, -1), (0, 0, -4.5), (1, 1, 0.5), (1, 0, -0.5), (0, 0, 5.5), (0, -1, -4.5), (-1, 0, 4.5), (-1, 0, -5.5), (-1, 0, 5.5), (-1, 1, 2.5), (0, -1, 4.5), (-1, 0, 7.5), (-1, 0, -4.5), (-1, 0, 7.5), (1, 0, -3.5), (0, -1, -3.5), (1, 0, 8.5)], [(1, 0, -1, 0), (-1, -1, 3.0625), (0, 1, -3.9375), (1, 0, 0.0625), (1, -1, 5.0625), (0, 0, 0.0625), (1, 0, -3.9375), (0, 0, -2.9375), (0, -1, -2.9375), (0, 0, -4.9375), (-1, 0, 7.0625), (-1, 0, 0.0625), (-1, -1, 8.0625), (1, 1, 1.0625), (0, 0, 7.0625), (1, 0, 1.0625), (-1, -1, 6.0625)], [(1, 0, -1, 1), (1, 1, 8.5), (0, -1, 7.5), (1, -1, -3.5), (1, 0, -3.5), (-1, 1, 7.5), (1, 1, -2.5), (-1, 0, -0.5), (-1, 0, -3.5), (0, 1, -4.5), (1, 0, -1.5), (1, 1, 2.5), (1, -1, -3.5), (0, 1, 7.5), (1, -1, -0.5), (0, 0, 3.5), (0, 0, 6.5)], [(1, 0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 6.8125), (-1, 0, -1.1875), (0, -1, 3.8125), (0, -1, -0.1875), (0, 0, 4.8125), (-1, -1, -0.1875), (1, 0, -2.1875), (1, -1, -3.1875), (0, 0, 3.8125), (0, 0, 1.8125), (-1, -1, -1.1875), (0, -1, 0.8125), (1, 0, -4.1875), (1, -1, 6.8125), (-1, -1, -4.1875), (0, 0, 7.8125)], [(1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1.4375), (-1, -1, 4.4375), (0, 1, -2.5625), (1, 0, -1.5625), (-1, 0, 3.4375), (1, 0, 0.4375), (1, 0, -2.5625), (1, 1, -4.5625), (0, 0, -2.5625), (0, 1, 2.4375), (-1, -1, 6.4375), (0, -1, -5.5625), (1, -1, 3.4375), (1, -1, 6.4375), (-1, 0, 9.4375), (-1, 0, 1.4375)], [(1, 0, 0, 1), (-1, 0, -3.5625), (0, -1, 9.4375), (1, 1, -4.5625), (-1, 0, 6.4375), (0, 1, -5.5625), (-1, -1, -1.5625), (0, 0, -0.5625), (1, 1, -2.5625), (-1, 0, 9.4375), (1, 0, 0.4375), (1, 0, 1.4375), (1, -1, 4.4375), (1, 1, -5.5625), (0, -1, 5.4375), (1, 0, 6.4375), (-1, 1, 0.4375)], [(1, 0, 1, -1), (1, 1, -2.125), (-1, -1, -1.125), (-1, 1, 5.875), (0, 1, -2.125), (0, -1, -1.125), (-1, 0, -4.125), (-1, 0, 2.875), (-1, 0, -2.125), (-1, -1, 6.875), (-1, 1, 1.875), (1, 1, -4.125), (1, -1, 8.875), (1, 0, 10.875), (-1, -1, 4.875), (1, -1, -1.125), (0, 0, -4.125)], [(1, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 1, -6.75), (-1, 1, -6.75), (1, 0, -0.75), (0, 1, -2.75), (0, -1, 4.25), (1, -1, 8.25), (1, -1, -5.75), (-1, 1, 6.25), (-1, 0, -2.75), (-1, 1, 3.25), (1, -1, 8.25), (-1, 0, 7.25), (0, 0, 4.25), (-1, 0, 0.25), (1, 0, 6.25), (1, -1, -2.75)], [(1, 0, 1, 1), (-1, 0, -0.3125), (1, 0, 0.6875), (1, -1, -3.3125), (0, 1, 7.6875), (0, 1, 4.6875), (-1, -1, -2.3125), (-1, 1, 3.6875), (-1, 1, -4.3125), (0, 1, 7.6875), (1, -1, 7.6875), (1, 1, 0.6875), (-1, -1, 6.6875), (0, 0, -0.3125), (0, 0, -4.3125), (1, -1, 1.6875), (-1, -1, -6.3125)], [(1, 1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 2.3125), (0, 1, -0.6875), (1, -1, 8.3125), (1, -1, 2.3125), (1, 1, -4.6875), (-1, 1, 3.3125), (0, 0, 2.3125), (-1, -1, -5.6875), (1, 0, -3.6875), (0, 0, 7.3125), (-1, 1, 7.3125), (-1, 0, -0.6875), (1, 1, -5.6875), (0, 0, 1.3125), (0, 1, -2.6875), (-1, 1, 9.3125)], [(1, 1, -1, 0), (0, -1, 6.0), (-1, 0, 6.0), (1, -1, -3.0), (1, 0, 5.0), (0, 1, 0.0), (1, 1, 2.0), (0, -1, -1.0), (1, 0, 3.0), (-1, 1, 7.0), (-1, 0, 3.0), (-1, 1, -6.0), (-1, 1, 2.0), (-1, 0, -4.0), (-1, -1, 1.0), (1, 1, 5.0), (-1, -1, -6.0)], [(1, 1, -1, 1), (0, -1, 5.75), (-1, 1, 2.75), (1, 1, 5.75), (0, 1, -3.25), (-1, -1, -2.25), (0, -1, 3.75), (1, -1, -6.25), (1, 0, 7.75), (1, 1, 1.75), (-1, 1, 6.75), (0, -1, 5.75), (-1, 0, -4.25), (1, 0, -6.25), (0, 0, -4.25), (1, -1, 5.75), (0, 1, 0.75)], [(1, 1, 0, -1), (-1, 0, -1.25), (-1, 0, 6.75), (0, -1, -6.25), (0, 0, -2.25), (-1, 1, 5.75), (-1, 1, 2.75), (0, 1, 6.75), (0, 0, 1.75), (0, 1, -4.25), (1, 1, 8.75), (-1, 1, -6.25), (0, 1, -2.25), (0, 1, 7.75), (-1, -1, -0.25), (1, -1, -0.25), (1, 0, 2.75)], [(1, 1, 0, 0), (-1, -1, -5.5625), (1, 0, 8.4375), (-1, 0, 4.4375), (0, 0, 0.4375), (0, 0, -0.5625), (-1, 1, -0.5625), (0, 0, 1.4375), (0, 1, 4.4375), (1, -1, 7.4375), (1, 1, 4.4375), (0, 1, -4.5625), (1, 0, -2.5625), (1, -1, -5.5625), (-1, 1, -5.5625), (-1, 1, 9.4375), (1, -1, 4.4375)], [(1, 1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, -1.5), (0, 0, 0.5), (1, 1, 5.5), (0, 0, -4.5), (-1, 0, 7.5), (0, 0, -1.5), (1, 0, 4.5), (0, -1, -2.5), (-1, 0, 1.5), (1, 1, -0.5), (1, -1, 7.5), (-1, 0, 4.5), (-1, -1, 6.5), (0, 1, -5.5), (-1, -1, 3.5), (1, 0, -5.5)], [(1, 1, 1, -1), (0, 1, -3.125), (-1, 0, 0.875), (-1, 1, 6.875), (1, 0, -4.125), (0, 1, -5.125), (1, -1, 6.875), (-1, 0, 4.875), (-1, 1, 4.875), (1, 0, 2.875), (-1, 0, -0.125), (1, 0, -2.125), (1, 0, 6.875), (-1, 1, -1.125), (-1, 0, -4.125), (-1, 1, 8.875), (-1, 0, -3.125)], [(1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, -1.1875), (1, -1, 8.8125), (1, 1, 6.8125), (1, 0, 3.8125), (0, 1, -2.1875), (1, -1, 7.8125), (1, 1, 3.8125), (-1, -1, 2.8125), (1, 0, -1.1875), (0, 1, -1.1875), (-1, 0, 5.8125), (1, 1, -6.1875), (0, 0, 2.8125), (1, 1, -1.1875), (1, -1, -5.1875), (-1, 1, -4.1875)], [(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, -3.125), (1, 1, 4.875), (-1, 1, -6.125), (-1, 1, 2.875), (0, 1, 1.875), (-1, -1, -5.125), (-1, 1, 2.875), (-1, 1, -2.125), (-1, 1, 3.875), (1, -1, 6.875), (1, 1, 1.875), (1, -1, 2.875), (1, 1, 6.875), (1, 1, 5.875), (0, 1, -2.125), (1, 0, -2.125)]]]
```

Comment: Note, it's generally disadvised to use built-in functions or classes as variable names. In this case, `file`. Rename it to, for example, `infile` or `fp` (for "filepointer").

Comment: you could post your first comment as the answer, it worked, thanks! I still dont know why it would work for like half my txt file and the rest was getting flush

Comment: That may be system dependent, or how Python is compiled for your system, to do with buffering etc. But I'm not sure on those details; somebody else may correct me on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never close the file, because you never call `file.close()` (note the parentheses; you have `file.close`). That may mess up your file writing.

Better yet, use a context manager (`with` statement), which will make sure the file is always closed, even if an exception occurs halfway writing.

```
with open("test0.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(mystr)
```

[See the documentation (end of section)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

That said, once your script ends, resources such as files should be closed by Python automatically. I'm not sure, however, if it will also *flush* any remaining text to such a file. If it doesn't, that's the cause of your problem.